# Cannot convert from IOrganizationService to IOrganizationService

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to debug a plugin in Linqpad but running into issues trying to import the plugin assembly. I have created an IOrganizationService object in my Linqpad script and passed it to the plugin, but now I get this error:

> cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService [c:\Users\meUser\AppData\Local\LINQPad\NuGet\Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies\Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies.8.2.0.2\lib\net452\Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll]' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService [c:\Users\meUser\Documents\dynamics\MyPlugin.Plugins\bin\Debug\MyPlugin.Plugins.dll]'

I've double checked that the version of the Microsoft.Xrm.sdk.dll matches in the Linqpad script and the plugin, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same version of `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll` for both? Is it possible that you ILMerged the `Microsost.Xrm.Sdk.dll` into the `MyPlugin.Plugins.dll`?

Comment: So I'm definitely ILMerging the xrm.sdk, both the lingpad script and visual studio are using 8.2.0.2, but if I view the xrm.sdk properties in VS it says 8.0.0.0, and the app.config has a line like this: <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" /> I updated this to 8.2.0.2 and tried reinstalling the nuget packages but doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ILMerge the Microsoft DLLs. You shouldn't need to do that because they are available on the CRM server. It is causing a type mis-match.